# Android Material Dialog not closing on dismiss

Tags: android

I am using the dismiss method but my material dialogue is not closing

```
new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).adapter(mMaterialSimpleListAdapter, null).cancelable(true).autoDismiss(false).title("Select a device to pair").show();
MaterialSimpleListAdapter = new MaterialSimpleListAdapter(new MaterialSimpleListAdapter.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onMaterialListItemSelected(MaterialDialog dialog, int index, MaterialSimpleListItem item) {
                if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(leScanCallback);
                }
                connectToDevice(((BluetoothDevice) item.getTag()),false);
                dialog.dismiss();
                loading.playAnimation();
                loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

How did you defined the "dialog" of dialog.dismiss?

MaterialDialog is an external library, so I don't know exactly how it works but try to do something like that:

```
MaterialDialog.Builder builder = new MaterialDialog.Builder(this).adapter(mMaterialSimpleListAdapter, null).cancelable(true).autoDismiss(false).title("Select a device to pair");
dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show()
```

Comment: The dialog is from the Material dialog that is passes to the MaterialSimpleListAdapter